# VB application built using visual studio 2015 installation to windows xp

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, windows-xp

I updated a vb windows forms application using visual studio 2015. I need to install this on a windows xp machine.

I updated my application to run using .net framework 4.0, the same as the one installed in the xp machine.

When I tried to install it the first time, it asked me to restart the machine, which I did. after restarting it gave me the error that installation is incomplete.

I have been researching all morning on how to fix it, i tried the dpca.dll solution, i tried restarting the windows installer service, i used msiexec to view the logs, and now it gives me the error that a dll required for this install to complete could not be run. I have no idea which dll, it doesn't say.

My application is fine. It builds and installs beautifully on windows 7 and above.

Please help me before I smash the windows xp machine into pieces.

Comment: Have you checked the xp's service pack?

Comment: Hi @F0r3v3r-A-N00b, i didn't but I made a discovery. It seems that I can run the executable itself without needing to install. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I came across a comment that i can run the executable itself, just needed to copy all the dll files and put it in the same folder as the executable. So I just copied the whole folder and run the exe on the xp machine and it works.